# How do I reverse this array?

Tags: c

```
char Chessboard[8][8] = {'r', 'n', 'b', 'q', 'k', 'b', 'n', 'r', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*',\
    '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', \
    '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '+', '+', '+', '+', '+', '+', '+', '+',\
    'R', 'N', 'B', 'Q', 'K', 'B', 'N', 'R'}; //Initializing board
```

So, I have this chessboard, and I want to turn it around so it faces the opponent, aka reversing the array so that the values are in reverse order. I just need a program that would reverse this array AND store it in the array Chessboard, so that it isn't simply a printf function.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Any ideas or code from your side that we can work with? Or do you just want us to write the code so you avoid any kind of effort?

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple really. This is not a reversal, but a rotation by 180 degrees. In terms of  coordinates you simply map `i,j` to `7-i,7-j`.

You'd make a type for a board:

```
typedef char Board[8][8];
```

And then you would use this function:

```
Board reversed(const Board board)
{
    Board result;
    for (int i=0; i<8; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<8; j++)
            result[i,j] = board[7-i,7-j];
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Should be `7-i`, `7-j`.

Comment: It's worth noting that you don't really need to do nested loops here, since mapping from `i,j` to `7-i,7-j` is equivalent to just viewing it as a 1-dimensional array of size 64 and mapping `i` to `63-i`. In fact, if you could be assured that the byte at offset 64 was a null byte, you could accomplish this reversal by simply doing a `strrev` (assuming your system has `strrev`).

Comment: @Mike you could do that kind of thing if you wanted, but why would you? What's so hard about the high level view expressed here?

Comment: I didn't say this way was hard. Please don't put words in my mouth. The point is only that if you're having trouble conceptualizing what's going on in two dimensions, it might be helpful to realize that all you're essentially doing is reversing one big flat array. Also, if performance was a concern (which, granted, it is almost certainly not in this case), having one iterator variable instead of two would speed things up a tad. Lastly, if you could just do the whole thing with a simple `strrev`, it would make your code a lot smaller and cleaner, albeit perhaps a bit less obvious for some.

Comment: Again, I wasn't saying you *should* do it as a flat array, I was only pointing out that you *could*, which IMO helps to conceptualize what's actually going on.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds suspiciously like someone's CS homework assignment....  Good luck on that nested looping test :-)

```
int i, j;
for(i=0;i<4;i++){
  //just give each entry the value of its mirror by doing a swap
  for(j=0;j<8;j++){
    char tmp = Chessboard[i][j];
    Chessboard[i][j] = Chessboard[7-i][7-j];
    Chessboard[7-i][7-j] = tmp;
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that you only have to go half way across the board in this particular example due to the swap.